# Called Method is empty, beginner jGrasp

Tags: java, object, methods, instance, jgrasp

```
public class AppleOrchard
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Rick...");
        BushelBasket rick = new BushelBasket(0);
        rick.print();
        rick.pick(11);
        rick.pick(22);
        rick.print();
        rick.eat(4);
        rick.print();
        rick.spill();
        rick.print();

        System.out.println("Newt...");
        BushelBasket newt = new BushelBasket(100);
        newt.print();

        System.out.println( newt.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( newt.isFull() );
        System.out.println( newt.getApples() );
        System.out.println( newt.roomLeftInBasket() );

        System.out.println("Michele...");
        BushelBasket michele = new BushelBasket(0);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
        michele.pick(25);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
        michele.pick(100);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );

        System.out.println("Herman...");
        BushelBasket herman = new BushelBasket(-5);  // should default to 0
        herman.print();

        System.out.println("Jon...");
        BushelBasket jon = new BushelBasket(300);  // should default to 125
        jon.print();

        System.out.println("Ron...");
        BushelBasket ron = new BushelBasket(20);  // starts with 20
        ron.print();
        ron.eat(50);  // can only eat down to zero apples
        ron.print();  // should see zero apples
        ron.eat(10);  // back to 10
        ron.pick(1000);  // basket can only hold 125 apples
        ron.print();  // should print 125

        System.out.println("Gary...");
        BushelBasket gary = new BushelBasket();  // should default to 0
        gary.print();
    }
}
```

---

```
class BushelBasket
{
    int apples;

    BushelBasket(int apples)
    {   
        if(apples>125)
            this.apples = 125;
        else if(apples < 0)
            this.apples = 0;
        else
            this.apples = apples;
    }

    public void spill()
    {
        apples = 0;
    }

    public void pick(int x)
    {
        apples = apples + x;
            if (apples < 0)
                apples = 0;
            else if(apples > 125)
                apples = 125;
    }

    public void eat(int x)
    {
        apples = apples - x;
            if (apples < 0)
                apples = 0;
            else if(apples > 125)
                apples = 125;
    }

    public int getApples()
    {
        return this.apples;  
    }

    public void print()
    {
        int x = getApples();
        System.out.println("This bushel basket has " + x + " apples in it.");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if (apples == 0)
        {   
            return true;
        }

        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        int full = 125;

        if (apples >= full)
        {   
            return true;
        }

        else 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public int roomLeftInBasket()
    {
        int room = 125 - apples;
        return room;                
    }
}
```

Okay so everything works perfectly and my output matches what it suppose but only when I comment out these two lines that I can't figure out.

```
BushelBasket gary = new BushelBasket();
gary.print();
```

These two lines are causing the error when I try to compile and I don't really understand how to fix it. The error it gives is "error: constructor BushelBasket in class BushelBasket cannot be applied to given types;" I kind of understand because all the other times when the method is called it has a number called with it but not sure what to do if it doesn't. Also if it doesn't have any object when the method is called its suppose to default to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if a method or constructor takes 1 argument, you must pass 1 argument.

Your BushelBasket constructor takes an int as argument, so you must call it with an int as argument.

You could add another constructor which would leave the field to its default value though:

```
int apples;

BushelBasket(int apples) {
    ...
}

BushelBasket() {
    // do nothing, so apples will be 0.
}
```

Or you could define another constructor without argument, which would call the one with an int argument and pass it 0:

```
int apples;

BushelBasket(int apples) {
    ...
}

BushelBasket() {
    this(0); // calls the other BushelBasket constructor.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly, I very much appreciate it!